# ref.child('ruta').update Duplica las consultas

Tags: firebase, typescript, google-cloud-platform, real-time

Quiero implementar una Functions en Firebase pero pasa algo extraño cuando se ejecuta una Cloud Functions.

Todo el flujo se encuentra correcto las busquedas se hacen bien sin embargo cuando agrego un update dentro de mi "if" los resultados se duplican.

Cuando comento la linea que ejecuta la función:

```
actualizatatusbroadcast(broad[c].id, cambio);
```

funciona correctamente pero si dejo que se ejecute esta función el console.log se imprime mas de una vez.

mi código es el siguiente

```
// Import the Firebase SDK for Google Cloud Functions.
'    use strict';
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';



// Import and initialize the Firebase Admin SDK.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.DeleteUserCirculo = functions.database.ref('/users/{pushId}').onUpdate((snapshot, event) => {

var after = snapshot.after.val();
var cambio = after.status;
console.log("El usuario con ID: ", after.id, "se le aplicará la regla ", after.status);


var chats_bg = admin.database().ref('chats/broadcast_group');
chats_bg.on('value', function(snapshot2)
{
    let broad = snapshot2.val();

    for (let c in broad)
    {
      console.log("esta es la vuelta", c);

      if (broad[c].type == 'broadcast_group' && broad[c].creatorUserId == after.id)
      {
        console.log("esta es la vuelta dentro del if", c);
        actualizatatusbroadcast(broad[c].id, cambio);
      }
      }
});
 return event.eventId;
       });
```

Mi función es esta y lo que hace es ir a actualizar el status de los nodos que cumplen con la condición del "if"

```
function actualizatatusbroadcast(broad, cambio)
{
 const ref = admin.database().ref();
  ref.child('chats/broadcast_group/' + broad).update(
    {
      status: cambio
    }
  );
}
```

Este es el log si dejo que se ejecute la función que realiza el update, se puede apreciar como se imprimen mas de una vez mis console.log que deje de prueba.
[image: Este es el log si dejo que se ejecute la función que realiza el update]

Si comento la linea que ejecuta la función que realiza el update todo se muestra bien
[image: log firebase]

La estructura del nodo donde realizo el update es el siguiente:
[image: nodo database]

Espero alguien me pueda ayudar a clarificar un poco el por que pasa esto y que es lo que no estoy considerando

Answer (score 0):

Revisiones previas:

1. Que no exista otra función que modifique `/users/{pushId}`. Puede que no sea tu caso. Pero vale la pena la aclaración.

   Un error común es hacer cambios cíclicos. En tu caso cambios en `/users/{pushId}` crean cambios en `chats/broadcast_group/`. Si existe alguna función que escuche esos cambios y a su vez haga cambios en `/users/{pushId}` entonces tendrás cambios disparándose uno en consecuencia del otro cíclicamente.
2. Actualiza la consola de logs.

   Logs repetidos en la consola es una molestía frecuente. Pero solo es de actualizar el feed, y se recargará con la cantidad real.

---

Ahora, veo que tienes dos problema en tu función:

1. Te falta usar `Promise` y
2. Estas editando `/chats/broadcast_group` en el mismo callback en el que estas recibiendo cambios.

**Acerca del uso de Promesas**

[Como podés leer en la documentación](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions?authuser=0) las funciones asíncronas deben retornar `null`, un objeto o una promesa (`Promise`). De esa manera el servidor sabe cuando la función ha terminado.

Aún cuando con los puntos anteriores hayas arreglado tu problema, te recomiendo fuertemente que devuelvas una promesa en tu función. Te explico:

En tu caso, con la penúltima línea del código `return event.eventId;` denotas que tu función ha terminado... Pero ojo! La siguiente llamada es asíncrona:

```
chats_bg.on('value', function(snapshot2) // Buscar valores en la Base de Datos
{
// ... No se ejecuta inmediatamente. Se espera a que la Base de Datos responda.
});
```

Lo que significa que se alcanzará el final de la función antes que se ejecute lo de arriba.

Como prueba de esto, en tu log podés ver que el mensaje de terminación `finished with status: 'ok'`, pero aún así se siguen mostrando logs.

Lo que sucede es:

1. El servidor recibe el mensaje de que la función ya terminó (aunque aún hay trabajo por hacer).
2. El servidor detiene la función.
3. Cuando la función se vuelve a ejecutar se continúa con el trabajo pendiente, ejecutando las líneas faltantes de la sesión anterior.

**Acerca de la escritura de `/chats/broadcast_groups`**

[De acuerda a la documentación](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write?authuser=0#listen_for_value_events) si usas `ref.on('value', ...)` se disparará el callback por cada cambio que haya en la referencia:

> Este método se inicia cuando se adjunta el agente de escucha y *nuevamente cada vez que cambian los datos* (incluidos los secundarios).

Esta sucediendo algo así como:

1. Recibir valor de `broadcast_group` y ejecutar el callback
2. Entra al if y hace un cambio.
3. Se dispara el callback nuevamente debido al cambio realizado en el paso dos
4. Se repite 2 y 3 indefinidamente.

Para evitar esto debes [leer los datos una sola vez](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write?authuser=0#read_data_once) usando el método `once()`. Toma en cuenta que `once()`, a diferencia de `on()`, devuelve una `Promise` con los datos leídos.

---

El siguiente código debería arregla ambos problema:

```
exports.DeleteUserCirculo = functions.database.ref('/users/{pushId}').onUpdate((snapshot, event) => {

  var after = snapshot.after.val();
  var cambio = after.status;
  console.log("El usuario con ID: ", after.id, "se le aplicará la regla ", after.status);


  var chats_bg = admin.database().ref('chats/broadcast_group');

  // Devolvemos una promesa que se resuelva cuando se termine la
  // actualizacion del broadcast.
  return chats_bg.once('value').then((snapshot2) => {
    let broad = snapshot2.val();
    let promesas = []; // Un array para guardar todas las promesas

    for (let c in broad) {
      console.log("esta es la vuelta", c);

      if (broad[c].type == 'broadcast_group' && broad[c].creatorUserId == after.id) {
        console.log("esta es la vuelta dentro del if", c);
        promesas.push(actualizatatusbroadcast(broad[c].id, cambio));
        // 'actualizatatusbroadcast' devuelve un Promise, guardamos todas las promesas
        // en un array para que se resuelvan juntas.
      }
    }

    return Promise.all(promesas);
    // Promise.all espera a que todas las promesas se cumplan para resolverse
  });
});

function actualizatatusbroadcast(broad, cambio) {
  const ref = admin.database().ref();
  // retornamos el Promise que se devuelve con 'update'
  return ref.child('chats/broadcast_group/' + broad).update(
    {
      status: cambio
    }
  );
}
```

Utilizamos la promesa devuelta por `once()` para devolver las promesas internas.

Con lo anterior, el servidor no detendrá la promesa sino hasta que se resuelvan las promesas de actualización (o hasta que se cumpla el timeout).

El código anterior debería ser autoexplicable, pero si aún tenés dudas revisa la documentación que te enlacé arriba.

Comment: Muchas gracias, con esto ultimo mi problema fué resuelto. Te lo agradezco, ya podré seguir avanzando

Comment: Si esta o cualquier otra respuesta ha resuelto su problema, por favor considera [aceptarla](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) clicando la marca de check (en forma de V debajo de la puntuación de la respuesta). Esto indica a la comunidad que has encontrado una solución y de paso os dará reputación a ambos (a tí y quien ha respondido). Por supuesto, no tienes ninguna obligación de hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

Hola @Nery Ortez primero muchas gracias por contestar, dando un poco de retro a los puntos que me indicas...

Las revisiones previas no hay ningún problema ya que en Firebase eliminé todas las Cloud Functions para centrarme en este problema por lo que este código que es el único que tengo.

Pasando a la recomendación y probando el código que me mandas ahora el código queda en un bucle infinito el cual solo se detiene al marcar un timeout.

[image: Firebase Coud Functions Log]

En la documentación de Google indican que se usa el Promise para controlar una llamada asíncrona y la estructura que me mandas la veo correctamente.

¿Alguna idea del por que esté pasando esto?

Comment: Mira... Estas haciendo un comentario en donde debe ir una respuesta... SO solo te notifica a ti cuando alguien da una respuesta nueva. Me dio por revisar tu pregunta otra vez... Si no, no me doy cuenta. Usa los comentarios.

Comment: Ya sé cual es el problema... Voy a actualizar mi respuesta en unos minutos.